# Random background picture CSS | RAILS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, random, background, selected

```
html{ 
    background: url(/assets/flower.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;   
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I make this code randomly choose from a selected number of pictures as background. I am using Rails 3, so have that in mind, if that will simplify the process of making this work.
THANKS! :D

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I've tried this so far: random_bg = ['bg1.png', 'bg2.png', 'bg3.png'].sample. The pictures don't show up though, unfortunately.:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your view file where you would like to display the background image, add this line

```
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    background: url(<%= randomized_background_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  }
</style>
```

Now in your application_helper

```
def randomized_background_image
  images = ["assets/foo.jpg", "assets/random.jpg", "assets/super_random"]
  images[rand(images.size)]
end
```

Comment: This works nicely! Is there some advantage with the above answer the user posted with the routing and etc?

Comment: The above answer might be better if you really want to separate css from the view files.

Comment: There's probably a way to do it, but it will be less than ideal. Your assets will have to be recompiled every time this page is hit because css changes every page hit. This will slow down your app significantly.

Comment: Best practice is to keep styles separated from the view, but that's assuming that that the assets are always static. In your case however, since you need to dynamically change style, I would make an exception for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've decided to drop this. Unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to create an actions with redirect to a random image the browser will follow the redirect.

app/controller/background_controller.rb

```
class BackgroundController < ApplicationController
  def image
    redirect_to "/assets/images/background_#{rand(10)}.jpg"
  end
end
```

This will randomly redirect to a background image between `background_0.jpg` and `background_9.jpg`

config/routes.rb

```
Something::Application.routes.draw do
  …
  get '/random_background.jpg', to: 'background#image'
  …
end
```

css

```
html{ 
  background: url(/random_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

---

Some more advanced would be to do something like this in a Middleware, so such a request won't need so whole rails stack.

app/middleware/random_background_middleware.rb

```
class RandomBackgroundMiddleware
  def initialize(app, count = 10)
    @app = app
    @count = count
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["PATH_INFO"] == "/random_background.jpg"
      [302, {"Location" => "/assets/images/background_#{rand(@count)}.jpg")}, '']
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

`config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "RandomBackgroundMiddlware"
```

`insert_before 0` is used to place it at the top of the Middleware-Chain

---

Or even better would be something like this in your webserver config. But I don't how or if this can be done.

Comment: Interesting though it doesn't look random, can you explain it briefly?

Comment: For the way the assets pipeline works in recent rails versions you should use "/assets/background_#{rand(10)}.jpg" in your controller instead of "/assets/images/background_#{rand(10)}.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

I did this by creating a random class name in the view like this:

```
<div class="homepage-banner-<%= rand(1..10) %>">
```

Then I just added multiple images to my css like this:

```
.homepage-banner-1
  background-image: image-url('homepage/homepage-feature-1.jpg')

.homepage-banner-2
  background-image: image-url('homepage/homepage-feature-2.jpg')

.homepage-banner-3
  background-image: image-url('homepage/homepage-feature-3.jpg')

etc.
```

Not sure if that's the best way, but it's very simple.

Comment: Nice :) I wonder if this might cause performance issues/bandwidth waste though if all the images are getting loaded each time?